# How to pass user data into all all views?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, passport.js

I can't work out how best to pass user details (email, name, etc.) to 'logged in' views (I'm using jade).

I'm using passport and have access to `session.passport.user` in my views but only the user's _id is saved on here, and i've been told it would be bad security practice to persist it locally in the session cookie.

I don't want to have to pass a user object to `res.render` on each controller that I need the user.

this is how i have sessions setting up locally

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  next(null, req, res);
});
```

and this is my middleware to check if a user is logged in

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

I have looked at dynamic helpers but I'm using express v3.0.0rc4.

Comment: Since your are using `passport`, the req should have a `.user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `res.locals` for this purpose.  Anything you put in that object will be available in the view context (unless, of course, it's overridden by a later context).  So, for example, you could modify your `isLoggedIn` middleware thusly:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // obviouisly, don't use static strings...
    // get these values from your authentication
    // mmechanism
    res.locals.user = 'username';
    res.locals.userEmail = 'user@domain.com';
    return next();
  }

  // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
  res.redirect('/');
}
```